# How do I block a specific version of a package to be installed by aptitude (or apt-get)?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I have a problem with a program crashing, and I suspect that only the latest version of the package has this problem, so I wish to block this particular version from ever being installed – but I still want to be able to upgrade to future versions.

I think I've read (somewhere, at some point) that the apt system allows for this, but now that I look for it I seem unable to find it.

How would I go about doing this?

P.S. I'm intentionally vague about which package I'm having problems with, as I want to understand this feature of Apt (if indeed it exists), and do not want suggestions specific to the program I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the `/etc/apt/preferences` file and add:

```
Package: unzip
Pin: version 2.7
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: unzip
Pin: version 3*
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

This will keep the package on ***2.7***, skip ***2.8***, ***2.9*** and upgrade to ***3**** when available.

Note that this is an **unnatural way** of not upgrading to an unstable package version. A better (and the **recommended way**) is to **hold** the package till the issues are resolved:

**dpkg**:

```
$ echo "package hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

[**Aptitude**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptitude-gtk/)

```
$ sudo aptitude hold package_name
```

Comment: To undo the hold with dpkg: `echo "package_name install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections` or with aptitude: `aptitude unhold package_name`

Answer (score 1):

aptitude allows this with the forbid-version option.

Select the version of the package in the UI and press 'F'

Alternatively you could do it via the command line interface, see manpage:

```
forbid-version
           Forbid a package from being upgraded to a particular version, while allowing automatic upgrades to future versions. This is useful for example to avoid a known broken version of a package,
           without having to set and clear manual holds.

           By default, aptitude will select the forbidden version to be the one which the package would normally be upgraded (the candidate version). This may be overridden by appending „=<version>“ to the
           package name: for instance, „aptitude forbid-version vim=1.2.3.broken-4“.

           To revert the action, „aptitude install <package>“ will remove the ban. To remove the forbidden version without installing the candidate version, the current version should be appended: „install
           <package>=<version>“.
```

Please note: This forbidden version is only honoured by aptitude. apt-get or other package managers will upgrade the package if run.

Comment: This information is stored in `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`, look for `ForbidVer:`. To verify which version(s) are forbidden use `aptitude versions packagename`, the forbidden versions will have a capital `F` in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'apt-get install package-version' to install a specific version of this package.

You can prevent to update this version with a specific configuration of /etc/apt/preferences. See 3.10 section at:

[APT HOWTO](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html)

You can do it too with apt-mark command. See "hold" option at:

[Ubuntu Manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-mark.8.html)